# Develop Add-on: How do you update the scripts?

Tags: python, add-on

Since Blender 3.5 I have the problem that Visual Studio Code with the Blender Development Tool only works with finished Blender versions.

But it just doesn't want to work any more when a Blender version is still a beta or alpha version.
Also "Reload Scripts", which is integrated in Blender, does not work. Also deactivating and reactivating the add-on in the preferences has no effect.

That means I have to close and reopen Blender every time I edit a script.

What is a better way to update the scripts? How do you do it?

Comment: Are you using the `Blender Development` extension? If yes then run visual studio code as an administrator, press `F1` to use `Blender: Start` command.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. I use VSC as administrator. But unfortunately this works only with finished blender versions. I'm getting this Error:

from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_concurrency_analyser.pydevd_concurrency_logger import ThreadingLogger, AsyncioLogger, send_concurrency_message, cur_time
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_concurrency_analyser.pydevd_concurrency_logger'

Comment: Which blender version are you using?

Comment: If you encounter problems using Blender Development VSC package, then you should most llkely report it on [its official bugtracker](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/blender_vscode/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails),  which is a way more suited place than here.